# Text AND Date in Excel Cell - Read Date Only

Tags: excel, vba

I have some text AND a date (seperated by a hyphen) in one excel cell e.g. "Anniversary - 12/12/2012"

I want to be able to read the date only and if it is greater than the current date - the cell should become highlighted.

Can this be done via excel functions or do I need to write some VBA?

MC

Comment: Is the text always the same? You might want to consider using a custom format for the cell, something like this             `"Anniversary - "mm/dd/yyyy` - If you do that then the cell will still display the same but the underlying value will be a simple date - you can then just do a simple comparison with today's date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the area with all values, and chose "Conditional Formatting". Select "More Rules" from "Highlight Cells Rules" and select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Put this formula in the rule description field:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID($A1,FIND(" - ",$A1)+3,10))>TODAY()
```

Don't forget to chose the formatting options with "Format..."

Comment: You might want to modify to answer the part about highlighting cells greater than the current date.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I thought I'd share the trickiest part of the formula first, because it takes some time to translate the menu item texts into English by using screenshots from Google. My Excel is German, but I wanted to provide the names in English :)

Comment: Nicely done.+1. Also note that US Excel uses commas where yours uses semicolons,e.g., `=DATEVALUE(MID($A1,FIND(" - ",$A1)+3,10))>TODAY()`